# Sitecore: Find the value of a field for a selected Item

Tags: sitecore

I'm trying to create some custom code inside my Sub Layout.

I have to build a newsletter, the newsletter can be composed on a number of article.
An article can be composed by a title / Sub title / Header and image.

Can be, because the Sub title or the image are not mandatory.
To avoid any empty space / missing image in the newsletter email, I would like to create a specific HTML based on the content.

If there is no image, don't show the Image control, if there is no Sub title, don't show the Sub Title control;

To do that, I'm using the following code which is not working :(

```
    Sitecore.Data.Database master = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");
Sitecore.Data.Items.Item home = master.GetItem("/sitecore/content/Home");

if(home != null && home.Fields != null)
{
string name = home.Fields["Image"].Name; -> Which Fields["Image"] returns null.
}
```

Is there another way to retreive the field of the selected article ? As my code is not working at all, I don't understand how to retreive the Field value of my selected Item.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, home.Fields is just checking to make sure that the Fields collection exists.  You aren't checking if there is a value in the Image field before trying to extract the name.

You probably need something like this:

```
if(home != null && home.Fields != null && home.Fields["Image"] != null)
{
   string name = home.Fields["Image"].Name;
}
```

Per your comments, it seems to be you are actually trying to pull the image field from the datasource of your component.  If you want to conditionally check for the image field before doing something in that case, there are a lot of possible null exceptions that I would want to handle.  The code should probably be something like:

```
var parent = ((Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControl)Parent);
if(parent != null){
   Item dataSourceItem = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(parent.DataSource) ? null : Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(parent.DataSource);

   if(dataSourceItem != null && dataSourceItem.Fields != null && dataSourceItem.Fields["Image"]!=null){
       string name=dataSourceItem.Fields["Image"].Name;
   }
}
```

Comment: Indeed, I forgot to add one line in the post. My code contains the check on the home.Fields["Image"]. It's always null.

Comment: My code is defined like you mentioned Jay.


I have defined a specific Datasource for each of my Sub Layout. Could that be the issue ?

The following control:

    <sc:FieldRenderer runat=server FieldName=Image /> was always empty.
    The support team told me to define the Datasource like
    
    <sc:FieldRendrer runat=server FieldName=Image Datasouce=<%#((Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Sublayout)this.Parent).Datasource %> />

So maybe, i have to do something like this in my C# code to habe the reference of my datasource ? Maybe that looking after another source ?

Thanks,

Comment: Sitecore support team helps me to solve my issue. The code would be the following string value = FieldRenderer.Render(Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(((Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Sublayout)this.Parent).DataSource), "Image");

Comment: Hey fix105, I'm glad you got the answer.  Sorry I've been offline.  I hadn't realized you had a datasource-driven component.  I will often do the databinding like that in a few lines to be able to make checks.  I'll update my answer to include a sample of how to do that.

Comment: Great. Thank you for your example. Cannot marked the answer as useful as I don't have 15 reputation. But the answer is really useful.

Comment: I think that should be var parent = (Sublayout)this.Parent;

Comment: The DataSource property is defined on Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControl. Sublayout inherits from that class.  I'll edit my response to include that namespace to differentiate from System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl

Answer (score 0):

Here is one simple way :

```
Sitecore.Context.Item.Fields["You field name"]
```